# Change the format of search result from JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, format

I am using javascript to search content from JSON file, below is my code:

```
var result = [];
var searchField = "equip_id";
for (var i=0 ; i < jsondata.array.length ; i++)  
   {
    if (jsondata.array[i][searchField] == SelectedEquip) {
    result.push(jsondata.array[i].group_name);
    }
}
```

And the output is a group name with the following format:

["groupname"]

I only want the groupname without [] and "". Because I need to use the groupname to search another JSON file. 
Anyone can help solve this problem?

Comment: your result is an array of strings ... `[]` shows it's an array, `""` shows it's a string ... `result[0]` will be the first (only?) value found - you can't remove the `""` because then it wont be a string!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show how you are using `result` after the loop. How do you display the output? Given `result` is an array you could have several matching items, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result as a string, how about:

```js
// Sample Data
var jsondata = {
  array: [{
    equip_id: 1,
    group_name: "a"
  }, {
    equip_id: 2,
    group_name: "b"
  }, {
    equip_id: 3,
    group_name: "c"
  }]
}, SelectedEquip = 3;

// Actual code
var result = '';
var searchField = "equip_id";
for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.array.length; i++) {
  if (jsondata.array[i][searchField] == SelectedEquip) {
    result = jsondata.array[i].group_name;
  }
}

// Sample output
console.log(result);
```

Using your code above, `result[0]` will give you the same output.  There's just no need to create and push to an array, if you are dealing with a single value.

Comment: This will only keep the last result.

Comment: Correct.  It seems there should only be one result here.